# How to update macOS Sierra 10.12 to 10.13?

Tags: macos-sierra

If I press *check updates* it updates only to 10.12.6, but I need macOS High Sierra 10.13. I'm using a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015).

Comment: i checked the update button in About and also Updates section in appstore. Didn't know I have to do it as shlck said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open *App Store* and on the right, find the link to *High Sierra*.

[image]

There, on the top left, you will find the link to download it, or open the existing installer (which macOS may have downloaded in the background).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Instead I got it done following [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-upgrade-my-Mac-OS-X-to-10-13-6-if-no-update-is-available-in-the-app-store-Currently-I-have-10-12-6):

> If you really want to go to High Sierra (10.13.6), you need to find
>   the macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 installer files, then follow Apple's
>   instruction to create bootable USB: [How to create a bootable installer
>   for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Then reboot your Mac, press the power and hold Option key,
>   choose the Install macOS disc and install.